# Removing .csv from @item().name in ADF

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory

In my Sink Table Name, I have the below paremeter:

```
@item().name
```

but it is creating the table as xxxxx.csv

What can I do to get rid of the .csv portion of the itemname when creating the sink table parameter. I found that I need to use Split() but it didn't work for me:

```
Split(@item().name,".",1)
```

Please note that I can't use substring because the parameter will refer to different table names with different lengths. So my approach was to look at the  as a separator and extract the characters before it as my table name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced the issue and the dynamic content you are using has incorrect syntax.

- This is a sample array that I have taken.

```
[{"name":"file1.csv"},{"name":"file2.csv"}]
```

- Inside for each, in a `set variable` activity, I used the following to extract just the filename (without '.csv').

```
@split(item().name,'.')[0]
```

[image]

- The following is the debug output:

[image]

- So, please change the dynamic content to `@split(item().name,'.')[0]`.

Comment: That was a great technique. the syntax was wrong. I used the one you sent and it all worked perfectly. thanks heaps